# Help identifying Italian uniform, rank, regiment

Tags: military, war, identification, uniform, italian

I'm hoping to learn the time period of the photo, any division, rank, and any other information y'all can glean. The photo was passed down so much information has been lost - it is possibly my grandfather's first cousin. Our family is Sicilian.

The back includes where the photo was developed in Torino, and "set 1939" (possibly the year?). I can read "Ricordo...Francesco" on the back but that's all I can decipher of the handwriting.  The photograph is about 6x4".

I was also wondering if there was recommended place to search for Italian military records.

Thank you very much/Grazie mile!

[image: Italian soldier formal portrait holding a sword standing next to a helmet on a stand covered in roses]

[image: back of photograph with address in Torino, "set 1939" and scribbly writing in Italian]

Comment: Not my period, and not a field I have any experience with but boots & jodhpurs scream cavalry to me.  If that is a saber in his hands and a horse head on the left sleeve, that would support that hypothesis. cf [this helmet](https://www.reddit.com/r/HistoryPorn/comments/un9253/colorized_italian_soldier_of_the_first_world_war/)  I wonder if the 692R on the plant stand is significant? @kimchilover is correct, it is 692R

Comment: I agree with MCW, but think the number is 692R.  The rank might be Sottotenente, the most junior officer rank in the Italian army in 1939.

Comment: The handwriting is quite difficult but I believe it's on two columns, maybe "Ricordo (del) nostro nipotte (...) non si scorda mai" and "(Mameli?) Francesco di Antonino".

Comment: 1.: https://comandosupremo.com/regio-esercito-uniforms/ suggests I was wrong about the rank.  2: The same source says the arm badge might be a specialty insignia, and the lack of rank insignia on the arm might indicate the person was a new recruit.  3: the "SET  1939" in the back of the photo might mean "September 1939"

Comment: My guess is that the 692R is just the photographer's serial so they could send out the right pictures if doing a large batch at once; it feels very high to be a unit number

Comment: Thank you all for the help!!